# How to create a menu item in KDE that executes a terminal command?

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, 17.10, kde, anaconda

I have been trying to accomplish this task for years and every time I try it, I fail miserably and simply give up completely after Googling it and trying for hours. This time though, I decided to seek help from you!

Logically speaking, It should be a very straightforward simple task as follows:

**Step 1:** Right-click on the menu button, then go to "Edit Applications".

[image]

**Step 2:** Click on "Add new item", assign a menu entry name then create your launcher or command.

No matter how many variations of commands I try, it is never working out. I tried to launch the Konsole terminal then execute the command, but the Konsole is not holding still and closing automatically even after issuing the right flag to keep it running.

```
konsole -e anaconda-navigator --noclose
```

[image]

Specifying the command directly also does not work out and simply renders nothing on the screen.

```
anaconda-navigator
```

[image]

I wonder why it has to be very hard like that. Your help will be greatly appreciated!

**My System Information - For Reference:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the `--help` option the `-e` should be the last part of the line:

```
-e <cmd>                  Command to execute. This option will catch all following arguments, so use it as the last option.
```

So, to run the command to keep it open, it would then be:

```
konsole --noclose -e anaconda-navigator
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The terminal window is opening but it is closing instantly after a second. It is still not working out for me even if the -e flag is at the end.

Comment: @Ken Can you try it with another command possibly?  All the tests I have ran at it seem to keep the terminal open even if it is a command that doesn't exist.  `konsole --noclose -e ls` returns a listing of my folder but keeps the window open.

Comment: All types of commands are not working out for me. The commands are just working if I am plugging them manually into the terminal.

Comment: @Ken, please show us a command line with `konsole --noclose -e some-command`, that does not work for you, and we can debug it in our systems. - An alternative might be to [install if necessary and] use old `xterm` like so, `xterm -fa default -fs 12 -hold -e lsb_release -a &`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I was able to do it, using the example of command

```
fortune | cowsay
```

1. Open a text editor and type

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   fortune | cowsay
   ```
2. Save file as `cow.sh` ( or any name you wish and note location path)
3. Open KDE Menu Editor ( note to use proper path to your cow.sh )

   Command:

   ```
   konsole --noclose -e /home/username/Documents/cow.sh
   ```
4. click save and test it!

Answer (score 0):

anaconda-navigator should run without any additional parameters.

Ensure the path to anaconda is in ~/.bachrc
i.e.

```
export PATH="/home/<user>/path/to/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Ensure conda is updated: (this next command will fail, but it will give you the correct command for updating your system.)

```
conda update
```

Otherwise, a plasma config file might require deletion/recreation. Try renaming one or both of the following files (Warning: Desktop settings will be set back to default!):

- ~/.config/plasmashellrc
- ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc

Then restart plasma:

```
killall plasmashell && plasmashell &
```